# Why doesn't the jQuery .html() method work with custom tags in IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, custom-tags

I have the following html code:

```
<mytag>
      Just Some Text
</mytag>
```

And I have this jQuery command

```
$('mytag').each(function () { alert($(this).html()); });
```

In all browsers except IE I'm getting the inner HTML, in IE I'm not. Anyone can shed any light on this mystery? I've tested this with IE8, Mozilla, Opera, Chrome and Safari

Comment: you're asking for the innerHTML of something that is not HTML.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because Internet Explorer doesn't **error correct** for that particular type of **invalid** HTML in the same way that the other browsers you have tested the code with do.

I would imagine that you can hack around it (it works for applying CSS) with:

```
document.createElement('mytag')
```

… but you would be better off writing HTML (or writing XML and serving it as application/xml).

Comment: Unfortunately i don't merely need to apply CSS to this tag. I need to extract it's innerHTML and manipulate it and i DO need to use a customtag.

Comment: +1 “custom tags” are not HTML and you cannot reasonably expect them to behave in any particular way in browsers.

Comment: rewrite you custom tags as `<span class="myCustomTag">..</span>`. That way you can search for them and they don't influence the layout.

Comment: @William — I said the hack will probably work for what you want. I just have no experience of that as I've never used it beyond getting `abbr` to work and have never needed to get the innerHTML of an `abbr` element, only to apply styling.

Answer (score 1):

For IE, you need put this in your tag -> `xmlns='mytag'`

```
<mytag xmlns='mytag'>
  Just Some Text
</mytag>
```

now IE and all other browsers can "see" your tag